# Postgres partitioning for large database suggestions

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

I am rebuilding a system and migrating all of the data from mysql to postgres (along with redis just as cache layer).
The structure is as follows :

- users table with under 5000 rows
- items table with a few billion rows
- chars table with under a million rows
- accounts table with under 200k rows
- each item row has a foreign key for chars(char_id)
- each char row has a foreign key for accounts(acc_id)
- each account row has a foreign key for users(user_id)

I have also added the users(user_id) foreign key to items table. This is to avoid having to join items + chars + accounts and users every time I simply want to look for items by userid.
I want to know the most efficient way to access the items rows. Most likely in the future that table will be sharded to a remote server when the server can't handle the whole.

Some places I read that partitioning is a good idea here, and others say indexing/views are sufficient.
So my idea is to partition items by user_id since queries will almost always be limited to that user's data. A typical query will be to SELECT ~100 or so items for a specific user that are on a char that is the correct type and this char also has to be on an account that is of the correct type (two joins).

My first question is, partitions by user, good? And if so, the ideal layout. And if not, what alternatives? Views?

A secondary question would be, should I put the char and account details on each item row? I don't mind wasting space if it means faster queries.

There's a lot to say and I hope everything makes sense. If it doesn't, please don't hesitate to ask for more details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Partitions on user would be good to go.
2. Personally, I don't recommend using CHAR. Also this will not improve the query performance.

Comment: To decide on a partitioning approach I would suggest thinking about how your items are split between users and how they will be queried. A partition per user may cause issues if the number of partitions grows exponentially and may also result in a bunch of tiny redundant partitions. You could use a hash partition to partition on a group of users (e.g. a partition per 100 users).
Good luck!
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: @pgyogesh "char" is just shorthand for a game "character" ^^ I am glad that partitions might be the way to go, seemed like the cleanest way so it will be good if it turns out to be the most efficient.

Comment: @LouisvanSenden The split is 1:1, every user would get a partition for his items. The queries will almost always be from that user while on the site, and only returning rows that belong to him. The only concern here is that some are vastly more active and have millions of items, while some others might only have a few hundred. Thanks for bringing up grouping, worth looking into.

Comment: @LAZ you could go down a wormhole and start thinking about dynamically creating partitions for users once they get above a certain count of items, then leaving all other users in the default partition. Just depends on how much/quickly you expect the DB to scale.
If items are queried on other cols like time, then you could approach it from a date range partition, like monthly/yearly partitions: items_2019_01 but if users are regularly querying across partitions (ie. looking for items across many months or years) it wouldn't be ideal.